# Find markers in view (that aren't within a cluster)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have about 2,000 markers on a map in clusters.

As the user pans / zooms the map, I want to find the markers that are in view and then show these locations in a table.

I'm looping through the markers and then using the below to see if the marker is in the bounds of the map.

```
if( map.getBounds().contains( markers[i].getPosition() ) )
```

From my understanding the markers are always in view, even if they're in a cluster. I need to check if the marker is truly visible.

I'm after the three blue markers in this image, ignoring the remaining clusters.
http://snag.gy/aCUBR.jpg

Full code:

```
var geocoder = null;
var markers = [];
var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;
var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';


function initialize()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15, //change back to 5
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3077361,-1.4317984),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    /* Markers within bounds */
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {


        $('.results tbody').empty();

        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++)
        {
            if( map.getBounds().contains( markers[i].getPosition() ) )
            {
                var stockist = markers[i].key;

                $('.results tbody').append('' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td><span class="red">' + stockist.name + '</span><br>' + stockist.address_1 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + stockist.postcode + '</td>' +
                    '<td>xkm</td>' +
                '</tr>');
            }
        }
    });

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,

    new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

    for( var key in data.stockists )
    {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.stockists[key].latitude, data.stockists[key].longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            draggable: false,
            icon: markerImage,
            key: data.stockists[key]
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }

    var zoom = zoom === -1 ? null : zoom;
    var size = size === -1 ? null : size;
    var style = style === -1 ? null: style;

    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        maxZoom: 11,
        gridSize: 100,
        styles: styles[style]
    });
}

function clearClusters(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Working example of code:**
http://46.101.40.40/map/map.html

As you'll see from this it presents 12 locations (not sure why it isn't 13...), I only need the locations for the 2 blue markers.

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including some sample data (a jsfiddle or a SO code snippet)?

Comment: @geocodezip I've updated the post with a link to working code with data included and set the zoom level to show the issue more clearly.

Comment: The [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be in the question itself, not a link to an external site that could go away or get "fixed" (and your "live" page isn't very "minimal"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if the marker is not clustered and is visible on the map check:

1. if the marker is visible
2. if the marker's map property is not null
3. if the marker is inside the map's viewport

(note that this code assumes [markerclustererplus](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html))

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster,'clusteringend',function() {
      var side_bar_html = "";
      for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
        if (gmarkers[i].getVisible() && (gmarkers[i].getMap() != null) && map.getBounds().contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition())){
          // add a line to the side_bar html
          side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].getTitle() + '<\/a><br>';
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered_separateMarkersInSidebar.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = null;
var markers = [];
var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;
var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
  'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';


function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11, //change back to 5
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3077361, -1.4317984),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  /* Markers within bounds */
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {


    $('.results tbody').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].getVisible() && (markers[i].getMap() != null) && map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {

        var stockist = markers[i].key;

        $('.results tbody').append('' +
          '<tr>' +
          '<td><span class="red">' + stockist.name + '</span><br>' + stockist.address_1 + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + stockist.postcode + '</td>' +
          '<td>xkm</td>' +
          '</tr>');
      }
    }
  });

  /* Geocode address on submit */
  document.getElementById('search-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });

  var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,

    new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

  for (var key in data.stockists) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.stockists[key].latitude, data.stockists[key].longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title: data.stockists[key].id,
      draggable: false,
      icon: markerImage,
      key: data.stockists[key]
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }

  var zoom = zoom === -1 ? null : zoom;
  var size = size === -1 ? null : size;
  var style = style === -1 ? null : style;

  markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: 11,
    gridSize: 100
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('search-value').value;

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      resultsMap.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
      resultsMap.setZoom(12);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function clearClusters(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var data = {
  "stockists": [{
    "id": "557",
    "retailer_id": "8162",
    "name": "Alfred Dunham & Sons Limited",
    "address_1": "56 Snape Hill Lane",
    "address_2": "Dronfield",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S18 2GP",
    "telephone": "01246 290205",
    "latitude": "53.3058795807",
    "longitude": "-1.46872179885"
  }, {
    "id": "643",
    "retailer_id": "5921",
    "name": "City Electrical Factors",
    "address_1": "120 Liverpool Street",
    "address_2": "Attercliffe",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S9 2PU",
    "telephone": "0114 2447181",
    "latitude": "53.3991836837",
    "longitude": "-1.42996239972"
  }, {
    "id": "1380",
    "retailer_id": "1047",
    "name": "Mitchells of Horley",
    "address_1": "1-9 Station Road",
    "address_2": "Horley",
    "address_3": "Surrey",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "RH6 9HW",
    "telephone": "01293 820229",
    "latitude": "51.1735617204",
    "longitude": "-0.160334794573"
  }, {
    "id": "1381",
    "retailer_id": "8045",
    "name": "Lawsons Crawley",
    "address_1": "Unit 4",
    "address_2": "Telford Place",
    "address_3": "Crawley",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "RH10 1SY",
    "telephone": "01293 535054",
    "latitude": "51.111860316",
    "longitude": "-0.182787540235"
  }, {
    "id": "1382",
    "retailer_id": "8163",
    "name": "Shaws Ironmongers Limited",
    "address_1": "112\/118 Duchess Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "South Yorkshire",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S2 4BL",
    "telephone": "01142 724289",
    "latitude": "53.3714802748",
    "longitude": "-1.46490033489"
  }, {
    "id": "1383",
    "retailer_id": "8627",
    "name": "M.K.M. Building Supplies Limited",
    "address_1": "110 Rutland Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "South Yorkshire",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S3 9PJ",
    "telephone": "0114 2709140",
    "latitude": "53.393997293",
    "longitude": "-1.47514511335"
  }, {
    "id": "1384",
    "retailer_id": "8628",
    "name": "M.K.M. Building Supplies Limited",
    "address_1": "201 Woodbourn Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "South Yorkshire",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S9 3LR",
    "telephone": "0114 2894210",
    "latitude": "53.3848381766",
    "longitude": "-1.43767094034"
  }, {
    "id": "1385",
    "retailer_id": "8173",
    "name": "Turner Hire & Sales Limited",
    "address_1": "426 - 432 London Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S2 4ND",
    "telephone": "0114 2581682",
    "latitude": "53.364329725",
    "longitude": "-1.47400630126"
  }, {
    "id": "1386",
    "retailer_id": "5920",
    "name": "City Electrical Factors",
    "address_1": "18 Hillfoot Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "South Yorkshire",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S3 8AA",
    "telephone": "0114 2755680",
    "latitude": "53.3949418548",
    "longitude": "-1.48566055099"
  }, {
    "id": "1387",
    "retailer_id": "6931",
    "name": "City Electrical Factors",
    "address_1": "Unit 4 Old Forge Business Park",
    "address_2": "Sark Road",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S2 4HG",
    "telephone": "0114 2585555",
    "latitude": "53.3634242859",
    "longitude": "-1.47251473647"
  }, {
    "id": "1388",
    "retailer_id": "1421",
    "name": "Alltools Limited",
    "address_1": "Woodbourn House",
    "address_2": "119-139 Staniforth Road",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S9 3HD",
    "telephone": "0114 224 3443",
    "latitude": "53.3902025569",
    "longitude": "-1.43158582647"
  }, {
    "id": "1389",
    "retailer_id": "4471",
    "name": "Pagets Builders Merchants LTD",
    "address_1": "94 Broadfield Road",
    "address_2": "Sheffield",
    "address_3": "",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S8 0XL",
    "telephone": "0114 292 3000",
    "latitude": "53.3607476212",
    "longitude": "-1.4770556"
  }, {
    "id": "1390",
    "retailer_id": "4664",
    "name": "Arnold Laver Timber World Limited",
    "address_1": "Sheffield Central",
    "address_2": "Little London Road",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S8 0UH",
    "telephone": "0114 255 7341",
    "latitude": "53.3544819891",
    "longitude": "-1.48314180348"
  }, {
    "id": "1391",
    "retailer_id": "6366",
    "name": "Hardcores Building & Paving",
    "address_1": "Rawson Spring Road",
    "address_2": "Hillsborough",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "South Yorkshire",
    "postcode": "S6 1PD",
    "telephone": "01142 310909",
    "latitude": "53.4102791612",
    "longitude": "-1.49901537862"
  }, {
    "id": "1392",
    "retailer_id": "8130",
    "name": "Timber Specialists",
    "address_1": "Herries Road South",
    "address_2": "Hillsborough",
    "address_3": "Sheffield",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "S6 1QS",
    "telephone": "0114 2316600",
    "latitude": "53.4111716609",
    "longitude": "-1.49750046288"
  }, {
    "id": "1393",
    "retailer_id": "8708",
    "name": "Arnold Laver Timber World Limited",
    "address_1": "Sheffield Mosborough",
    "address_2": "Olympic Sawmillsad",
    "address_3": "Oxclose Park Road North",
    "address_4": "Sheffield",
    "postcode": "S20 8GN",
    "telephone": "0114 2764800",
    "latitude": "53.3250344796",
    "longitude": "-1.34387258212"
  }, {
    "id": "1394",
    "retailer_id": "8459",
    "name": "LBS Builders Merchants Limited",
    "address_1": "Ferryboat Close",
    "address_2": "Enterprise Park",
    "address_3": "Swansea",
    "address_4": "",
    "postcode": "SA6 8QN",
    "telephone": "01792 702703",
    "latitude": "51.6569808054",
    "longitude": "-3.91979196897"
  }]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<article class="stockists">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="search-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-field" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Town, County or Postcode" id="search-value" value="SM14NG">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-orange btn-upper btn-find" type="submit" id="search-button">Find Stockist</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="map" id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>

      <table class="results" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Stockist</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
            <th>Distance</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```